# Error adding duplicate key to Dictionary in script task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

The script has been running well for ages, but has suddenly started falling over stating

```
Error: 0x0 at (SCR) GetLineageIDs, ProcessDataFlowTask error:: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at ST_b90e02c5aa5e4a7a992a1a75c6255cfa.ScriptMain.ProcessDataFlowTask(TaskHost currentDataFlowTask)
```

The objective is to get lineageIDs mapped to the actual column name in my SSIS package (2012,so  no 2016 lineage functionality).

I get that I am trying to add a key that has already been added to my dictionary in the following script, I'm not sure how and why it has suddenly started to error, full script below.  I think I need some sort of `if` block in my `ProcessDataFlowTask` method, any pointers would be gratefully received and an explanation as to why the duplicate key error is suddenly appearing?

```
namespace ST_b90e02c5aa5e4a7a992a1a75c6255cfa
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.  Do not change the name, attributes,
    /// or parent of this class.
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {


        Dictionary<int, string> lineageId = null;

        public void Main()
        {

            try
            {
                // Grab the executables so we have to something to iterate over, and initialize our lineageIDs list
                // Why the executables?  Well, SSIS won't let us store a reference to the Package itself...
                Dts.Variables["User::execsObj"].Value = ((Package)Dts.Variables["User::execsObj"].Parent).Executables;
                Dts.Variables["User::lineageIds"].Value = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                lineageId = (Dictionary<int, string>)Dts.Variables["User::lineageIds"].Value;

                Executables execs = (Executables)Dts.Variables["User::execsObj"].Value;

                ReadExecutables(execs);

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //An error occurred.  
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "SSIS variable read error:", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }  

        }

        private void ReadExecutables(Executables executables)
        {

            try
            {

                foreach (Executable pkgExecutable in executables)
                {
                    if (object.ReferenceEquals(pkgExecutable.GetType(), typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost)))
                    {
                        TaskHost pkgExecTaskHost = (TaskHost)pkgExecutable;
                        if (pkgExecTaskHost.CreationName.StartsWith("SSIS.Pipeline"))
                        {
                            ProcessDataFlowTask(pkgExecTaskHost);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (object.ReferenceEquals(pkgExecutable.GetType(), typeof(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ForEachLoop)))
                    {
                        // Recurse into FELCs
                        ReadExecutables(((ForEachLoop)pkgExecutable).Executables);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //An error occurred.  
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ReadExecutables error:", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }  

        }

        private void ProcessDataFlowTask(TaskHost currentDataFlowTask)
        {

            try
            {

                MainPipe currentDataFlow = (MainPipe)currentDataFlowTask.InnerObject;
                foreach (IDTSComponentMetaData100 currentComponent in currentDataFlow.ComponentMetaDataCollection)
                {
                    // Get the inputs in the component.
                    foreach (IDTSInput100 currentInput in currentComponent.InputCollection)
                        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 currentInputColumn in currentInput.InputColumnCollection)
                           lineageId.Add(currentInputColumn.ID, currentInputColumn.Name);


                    // Get the outputs in the component.
                    foreach (IDTSOutput100 currentOutput in currentComponent.OutputCollection)
                        foreach (IDTSOutputColumn100 currentoutputColumn in currentOutput.OutputColumnCollection)
                            lineageId.Add(currentoutputColumn.ID, currentoutputColumn.Name);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //An error occurred.  
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ProcessDataFlowTask error:", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }  


        }
        #region ScriptResults declaration
        /// <summary>
        /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
        /// result of the script.
        /// 
        /// This code was generated automatically.
        /// </summary>
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }


}
```

Comment: In addition to the approved answer, I also found out that placing Data Flow tasks preceded by the above script task in sequence containers per dataflow task avoids the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'duplicate key' error occurs if you have a duplicate column name in any of the data flows in the package. I had this problem before and I solved it by adding the following 2 steps.

**Step 1**
Make the following changes to the ProcessDataFlowTask method at both instances of lineageId.Add(...)

> Remember to use currentOutputColumn.Name instead of currentInputColumn.Name at the second instance

Change from

```
lineageId.Add(currentInputColumn.ID, currentInputColumn.Name);
```

To

```
strNewID = currentDataFlowTask.Name + "_" + currentInputColumn.ID.ToString();
lineageIDs.Add(strNewID, currentInputColumn.Name);
```

> Basically giving a unique name for the Column Name by adding the Data Flow Name plus the  '_' (Underscore) as a prefix.

**Step 2**
Since we have modified the Column names while adding to the LineageIDs collection, we need to use the modified column name, (i.e. Prefix Data Flow Name plus the  '_' (Underscore)) when comparing column names in **Input0_ProcessInputRow** method in another script task, which is required and you have not copied above.

```
    string newColNum = "DataFlowTaskName_" + Row.ErrorColumn.Value.ToString();
    if (lineageIDs.ContainsKey(newColNum))
        Row.ErrorColumnName = lineageIDs[newColNum];
```

Note: In above code **DataFlowTaskName_** is hard coded value and needs to be replaced with the Data Flow Task name in which your second script task exists, since it is not available in the Input0_ProcessInputRow method we need to hard code it.

This is just one way of doing it, May be you can find another way of handling the duplicates, this is how I did and it worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much MSBI-Geek, exactly the info I needed and the explanation was really clear.